Program associated with custom file extension isn't receiving command line arguments
When Python is first installed, the extension .py is associated with C:\windows\py.exe, which runs the Python script. Now I do a lot of Python development, so I set it to open with my IDE instead, but I still want the convenience of being able to just run a Python script without having to open a terminal and type out "python script.exe", so I set the extension ".pyrun" to open with py.exe, so now I can just save those files with .pyrun and have them open automatically. So far so good, but here's the problem:
When .py files are associated with py.exe, running them from the terminal with arguments passes on those arguments to the Python script, but that doesn't happen for the new .pyrun files.
I created a Python script to print out all the command line arguments and tested this.
So the question is how to make it work so that command line arguments are passed on to the Python script.
Things I tried:

Creating a batch file @python.exe %* and associating that with .pyrun - didn't work.
Adding .pyrun to the PATHTEXT environment variable: Also didn't work.

What I want:
To run script.pyrun abc 123 xyz and be able to access abc 123 xyz from inside script.pyrun.
As stated, I can do this when .py files are associated with py.exe (replace .pyrun with .py) with sys.argv but when I try the above sys.argv doesn't have the arguments.

If you used PATHTEXT (as you typed), .. it's PATHEXT.  If I were you, I would try to understand the relationship between *.pyrun -> <your_variable_keyname> -> shell -> VERB -> command in the registry.  I wouldn't have done it this way. I would have given myself a right click to open in the IDE or other way around.. not a new extension.
